# Subspaces of Hom(V,V)

Tags: vector-spaces

I'm finding this particular question difficult to wrap my head around.

$V$ is a non-zero vector space. Let $T \in Hom(V,V)$. Show that $\lbrace S \in Hom(V,V) : S\circ T = T \circ S \rbrace $ is a subspace of $Hom(V,V)$

Now if I am not mistaken $Hom(V,V)$ is the vector space of linear functionals from V to V. I am unable to connect that any further or indeed know if I am right in making than claim.

Steps/tips for the proof would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try to proof that the set $S$ satisfies the conditions to be a subspace.

Comment: You need to show that your set is not empty (hint: it contains $T$), is clsed under addition (question: how is addition defined there in the first place?) and scalar multiplication (again: defined how?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, $\operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$ is the space of linear **transformations** from $V$ to $V$ (you're misusing the term "functional" here).

In any case, you need to show that the set defined in your question passes the "subspace test", i.e. that it's closed under scalar multiplication and addition. In particular:

- For any scalar $\alpha$ and $S$ satisfying $S \circ T = T \circ S$, show that
  $$
  (\alpha S) \circ T = T \circ (\alpha S)
  $$
- For any $S_1,S_2$ both satsifying $S_i \circ T = T \circ S_i$, show that
  $$ 
  (S_1 + S_2) \circ T = T \circ (S_1 + S_2)
  $$

Comment: And we must show that it is non empty.